# Retrieve attributes from a GeoJSON feature in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I'm working on a webmap using `OpenLayers 3` and vector layers, `geoJSON`. I've managed to render the layers and add click interactions:

```
        select = new ol.interaction.Select({

            condition: ol.events.condition.mouseclicked,
            style: myStyle,
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            interactions:
            ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select]),
```

The interaction works fine, it sets a new style to the selected feature (borders of the selected country etc).

What I want is to retrieve the selected feature's id from the geoJSON file and use that to know what country is selected. Depending on what country is selected a network (lines) will be drawn from that country to other countries, retrieved from a DB.

Is there a way of doing this? I've tried the following (without proper formatting):

```
select = new ol.interaction.Select({

            condition: ol.events.condition.mouseclicked,
            style: myStyle,
        });
var features = select.getFeatures();
var feature = features.item(0);
var id = feature.getId();
```

This gives me an `id` that is undefined even though the feature has an `id` in the geoJSON file.

Is there another way of doing this? I've searched around the web and this forum without finding an answer.

This is a snippet of my geoJSON file, all features have the same properties:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },                                                                          
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "sovereignt": "Afghanistan", "id": 1 }, 
"geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 61.210817091725744
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your GeoJSON file? Looks like the id is not provided in the correct way. Otherwise what you were trying should have worked. On a side note, there is no `ol.events.condition.mouseclicked`.

Comment: Thanks for comment: about the mouseclicked, thanks for the note, it should be singleClick. I've updated the question with a snippet of my geoJSON file.

Comment: Your GeoJSON does not have an id for a feature. See b-eyes's answer below. What your GeoJSON has is features with two attributes, 'id' and 'sovereignt'. So you'll have to use `feature.get('id')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var id = feature.get('id');
```

As far as I know

```
var id = feature.getId();
```

gives you an internal OL3 feature id, not the JSON id.

Comment: This is incorrect. `feature.getId()` does not return an internal OpenLayers feature id, it returns the server's id for the feature. And `feature.get('id')` does not return the GeoJSON id, it returns the value of the feature's `id` attribute (just like `feature.get('sovereignt')` returns the value of the feature's `sovereignt` attribute).

Answer (score 5):

you have to set the id outside of the properties ... your geoJson Should look like that :

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" },                                                                          
"features": [
{ 
"type": "Feature",
"id": 1 ,
"properties": { "sovereignt": "Afghanistan"}, 
"geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 61.210817091725744 ...] ] ] ]
...
```

Comment: Correct. The id in the above snippet will be returned with `feature.getId()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! The solution in this case was:

```
var id = feature.get('id');
```

This returns the geoJSON id.

Whereas:

```
var id = feature.getID();
```

returns the openLayers id, just as Anders Finn pointed out above.

Thanks again for guiding!

Comment: In this case the solution is correct, but the explanation is misleading. See my comment on Andreas Finn's post below.